# I can't successfully connect to s3 according to the Quarkus documentation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I cannot successfully connect to s3 according to the Quarkus documentation, but I can connect to s3 through AWS CLI. Will you also encounter such a problem?

I used [Quarkus documentation](https://docs.quarkiverse.io/quarkus-amazon-services/dev/amazon-s3.html) try to use s3 in my Quarkus project, but whatever I do, the error tells me the bucket does not exist, but I can use the AWS CLI to upload a file to that bucket.

This is my resource:

```
    @Path("/s3")
public class S3SyncClientResource extends CommonResource {
    @Inject
    S3Client s3;

    @POST
    @Path("upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(FormData formData) throws Exception {

        if (formData.filename == null || formData.filename.isEmpty()) {
            return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }

        if (formData.mimetype == null || formData.mimetype.isEmpty()) {
            return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }

        PutObjectResponse putResponse = s3.putObject(buildPutRequest(formData),
                RequestBody.fromFile(formData.data));
        if (putResponse != null) {
            return Response.ok().status(Status.CREATED).build();
        } else {
            return Response.serverError().build();
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Path("download/{objectKey}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public Response downloadFile(String objectKey) {
        ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse> objectBytes = s3.getObjectAsBytes(buildGetRequest(objectKey));
        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(objectBytes.asUtf8String());
        response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + objectKey);
        response.header("Content-Type", objectBytes.response().contentType());
        return response.build();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<FileObject> listFiles() {
        ListObjectsRequest listRequest = ListObjectsRequest.builder().bucket(bucketName).build();

        //HEAD S3 objects to get metadata
        return s3.listObjects(listRequest).contents().stream()
                .map(FileObject::from)
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(FileObject::getObjectKey))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

    abstract public class CommonResource {
      @ConfigProperty(name = "bucket.name")
      String bucketName;

    protected PutObjectRequest buildPutRequest(FormData formData) {
        return PutObjectRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .key(formData.filename)
                .contentType(formData.mimetype)
                .build();
    }

    protected GetObjectRequest buildGetRequest(String objectKey) {
        return GetObjectRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .key(objectKey)
                .build();
    }

}
```

and this is my application.properties:

```
quarkus.s3.aws.region=ap-northeast-2
quarkus.s3.aws.credentials.type=default
quarkus.s3.aws.credentials.type=default
```

this is my pom.xml

```
  <dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
  <artifactId>url-connection-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkiverse.amazonservices</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-amazon-s3</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
  <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and I'm sure I configured .aws/credentials and I can use aws cli to upload my file to my bucket but when i try to use this upload api it will till me this err:

```
 software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.NoSuchBucketException: The specified bucket does not exist (Service: S3, Status Code: 404, Request ID: d436fe05-9929-434a-94ed-42e5f50c5a0f, Extended Request ID: s9lzHYrFp76ZVxRcpX9+5cjAnEH2ROuNkd2BHfIa6UkFVdtjf5mKR3/eTPFvsiP/XV/VLi31234=)
```

and i make sure this bucket is exist!!

Comment: Unfortunately you have not provided enough information for us to assist you. Please Edit your Question to show us your code and the _exact_ error message you are receiving.

Comment: Thanks for your remind, I've updated some details for this question.

Comment: Do you run the the application on the same environment as the cli command? I mean are the application hosted in docker and your cli command running from the host or something like that?

Comment: yes I run the application on the same environment as the cli command.